# Where should I put a logic for querying extra data in CQRS command flow

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, cqrs

I'm trying to implement simple DDD/CQRS architecture without event-sourcing for now.

Currently I need to write some code for adding a notification to a document entity (document can have multiple notifications).

I've already created a command NotificationAddCommand, ICommandService and IRepository.

Before inserting new notification through IRepository I have to query current user_id from db using NotificationAddCommand.User_name property.

I'm not sure how to do it right, because I can

1. Use `IQuery` from read-flow.
2. Pass user_name to domain entity and resolve user_id in the repository.

Code:

```
public class DocumentsCommandService : ICommandService<NotificationAddCommand>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Notification, long> _notificationsRepository;

    public DocumentsCommandService(
        IRepository<Notification, long> notifsRepo)
    {
        _notificationsRepository = notifsRepo;
    }

    public void Handle(NotificationAddCommand command)
    {
        // command.user_id = Resolve(command.user_name) ??
        // command.source_secret_id = Resolve(command.source_id, command.source_type) ??
            foreach (var receiverId in command.Receivers)
            {
                var notificationEntity = _notificationsRepository.Get(0);
                notificationEntity.TargetId = receiverId;
                notificationEntity.Body = command.Text;
                _notificationsRepository.Add(notificationEntity);
            }            
    }
}
```

What if I need more complex logic before inserting? Is it ok to use IQuery or should I create additional services?

Comment: The command handler should be injected with another specialized service. Your code is very weird by the way. I'm sure it doesn't reflect at all the language of domain experts when they describe the "add notification" use case. Anyway, even "adding" a notification makes no sense... a notification lets you know about something that happened, like an event. Are you trying to re-write history?

Comment: The notification is like a message about something, it contains notificationBody and  notificationTargetUserId properties

Answer (score 1):

The idea of reusing your `IQuery` somewhat defeats the purpose of CQRS in the sense that your read-side is supposed to be optimized for pulling data for display/query purposes - meaning that it can be denormalized, distributed etc. in any way you deem necessary *without* being restricted by - or having implications for - the command side (a key example being that it might not be immediately consistent, while your command side obviously needs to be for integrity/validity purposes).

With that in mind, you should look to implement a contract for your write side that will resolve the necessary information for you. Driving from the consumer, that might look like this:

```
public DocumentsCommandService(IRepository<Notification, long> notifsRepo,
                               IUserIdResolver userIdResolver)

public interface IUserIdResolver
{
    string ByName(string username);
}
```

With `IUserIdResolver` implemented as appropriate.

Of course, if both this and the query-side use the same low-level data access implementation (e.g. an immediately-consistent repository) that's fine - what's important is that your architecture is such that if you need to swap out where your read side gets its data for the purposes of, e.g. facilitating a slow offline process, your read and write sides are sufficiently separated that you can swap out where you're reading from without having to untangle reads from the writes.

Ultimately the most important thing is to know *why* you are making the architectural decisions you're making *in your scenario* - then you will find it much easier to make these sorts of decisions one way or another.

Comment: I've got your point and agree that read and write sides should be separated.

Comment: @Batavia
As I understand IRepository should not contains generic query methods but 
only get/update/insert/remove aggregate root methods.

So probably any exceptional logic should be placed into corresponding small
services (IUserIdResolver etc.)

Comment: You're right about not containing generic query methods but that's why you make a very specific repository containing a very specific query method that's not exposed on your general interface but just in your implementation

Answer (score 0):

In a project i'm working i have similar issues. I see 3 options to solve this problem

1) What i did do is make a UserCommandRepository that has a query option. Then you would inject that repository into your service.

Since the few queries i did need were so simplistic (just returning single values) it seemed like a fine tradeoff in my case.

2) Another way of handling it is by forcing the user to just raise a command with the user_id. Then you can let him do the querying.

3) A third option is ask yourself why you need a user_id. If it's to make some relations when querying the data you could also have this handles when querying the data (or when propagating your writeDB to your readDB)